# Disable locator-removal in LocatorPane

Tags: locator

is there a way to DISABLE the ability to remove points with ALT-click (APPLE-click) from a locator pane?
I'm writing a code that allows users to manually label objects in an image by connecting two consecutive points by a line. When the user is able to remove an arbitrary point from within the list, the connections between the points get messed up. Consider this snippet:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
Dynamic[Graphics[Line[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ Partition[pts, 2]]], 
LocatorAutoCreate -> All]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points can be created by  <kbd>Mouse click</kbd> alone, but deleted only with <kbd>Click + Alt</kbd>, so we can capture MouseClicks and pass them to `LocatorPane` only if  <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not pressed.

```
EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked" :> {}}, 
                PassEventsDown -> Dynamic[! CurrentValue["AltKey"]]
            ] &[

 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Dynamic[Graphics[Line[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ Partition[pts, 2]]], 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> All]

]
```